# Does webpack 2.x tree shake dead code in NPM modules as well?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

When bundling, does webpack 2.x remove dead code on npm packages and their dependencies that is not currently being used as well?

I understand that it removes things like functions in your code that are not being imported/executed. Does it do the same with npm packages that I use? For example, if I only used one function from lodash, does it bundle entire lodash npm packages or just the relevant code that is necessary for execution.

I wasn't able to find any information on this specifically.